# Complete intersections in projective spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, birational-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be an arbitrary smooth projective variety over a field $k$.

Do there exist:

- a smooth complete intersection $X'$ in a projective space.
- a surjective morphism of $k$-varieties $X'\to X$ ?

Comment: There does not exist such a pair $(X',f:X'\to X)$ if the dimension of $X$ is at least $3$ and the Picard rank of $X$ is $\geq 2$.  By the Grothendieck-Lefschetz Theorem on Picard groups, the restriction homomorphism of Picard groups, $\text{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^n)\to \text{Pic}(X')$, is a bijection.  In particular, every invertible sheaf on $X'$ is either trivial, ample, or antiample.  So if there is such a morphism, it is finite of some degree $d>0$.  Now you can use norms to conclude that $\text{Pic}(X)[1/d]\to \text{Pic}(X')[1/d]$ is injective.  But $\text{Pic}(X')$ is rank $1$.

Comment: Are there obstructions in dimensions 1 and 2?

Comment: @byu. "Are there obstructions in dimensions $1$ and $2$?"  Yes.  In dimension $2$, the Grothendieck-Lefschetz Theorem on algebraic fundamental groups implies that $X'$ has trivial algebraic fundamental group.  Thus the, degree of the finite part of the Stein factorization of $f$ is an upper bound on order of the algebraic fundamental group of $X$.  Thus, if the algebraic fundamental group of $X$ is infinite, then there exists no pair $(X',f:X'\to X)$.